# Create JSON array from DOM and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying an array in JavaScript with the following format by querying the DOM via JQuery:

```
 [
       {
         "start": moment("10/03/2017","DD/MM/YYYY"),
         "end": moment("18/03/2017", "DD/MM/YYYY")
       },
       {
         "start": moment("01/04/2017","DD/MM/YYYY"),
         "end": moment("05/04/2017", "DD/MM/YYYY")
       },
       {
         "start": moment("11/04/2017","DD/MM/YYYY"),
         "end": moment("15/04/2017", "DD/MM/YYYY")
       }
     ]
```

I tried to create a JavaScript `Object` in JQueries `each()` function to do this but it is not working:

```
var avail_fruits = Array();
    $(".avails").each(function(i, objer) {
        //test
        var ndate_group = $(objer).val().split(",");
        var obj_date = new Object();
        obj_date.start = moment(ndate_group[0],"DD/MM/YYYY");
        obj_date.end = moment(ndate_group[0],"DD/MM/YYYY");
        console.log(obj_date);
        avail_fruits.push(obj_date);
    });
```

Comment: Post your HTML also

Comment: I am not using any html, I have to put the json variable in disable range  in this plugin.
http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/calentim-date-time-range-picker/full_screen_preview/20099228?_ga=2.62034540.175328666.1557898468-1841774582.1548326341

Comment: I mean the `$(".avails")`. What are you getting when you `var ndate_group = $(objer).val().split(",");`

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="avail" class="avails" value="05/18/2019,07/30/2019">

Comment: What is not working? What are you getting in `avail_fruits`? Code looks fine. It should be working. Just for `obj_date.end = ` should have `ndate_group[1]` instead of `ndate_group[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can achieve what is required by extracting the `start` and `end` dates as strings from each `<input/>` element with jQuery like this:

```
const [start, end] = $(this).val().split(',');
```

You can then parse those strings via moment's `utc()` method as shown below:

```js
/* Declare results array */
const avail_fruits = [];

/* Iterate each input with avails class*/
$('.avails').each(function() {
  
  /* Extract start,end date string from input value */
  const [start, end] = $(this).val().split(',');
  
  /* Parse start,end date strings with moment. Use utc()
  to avoid timezone conversion */
  avail_fruits.push({
    start : moment.utc(start, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    end : moment.utc(end, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  });
  
});

console.log(avail_fruits)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" name="avail" class="avails" value="10/03/2017,18/03/2017"> 
<input type="hidden" name="avail" class="avails" value="01/04/2017,05/04/2017"> 
<input type="hidden" name="avail" class="avails" value="11/04/2017,15/04/2017">
```

Comment: Thanks, I am doing  the basic mistake for not pushing directing json instead, i was creating object. :(

Comment: @IntekhabKhan no worries - glad I could help!